# MS Access Update Area Code

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update the area code in my database from 206 to 209 but I have no idea to update that and keep the rest of the phone number. This is what I have right now...

```
UPDATE Employees
SET HomePhone = 209
WHERE HomePhone Like '*206*';
```

It is suppose to look like this (209) 555-5555

Comment: is your HomePhone column a Text column type, or a numeric? How does the raw data look in the table? does it have brackets and dashes?

Comment: HomePhone is a Text datatype. And yes it does have parenthesis and a dash. Ex: (209) 555-5555

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I recommend that you make the like condition stricter, like this. Otherwise you can update the phones where '206' appears elsewhere (not only in the area code)

```
UPDATE Employees
SET HomePhone = Replace(HomePhone, "(206) ", "(209) ")
WHERE HomePhone Like '(206) *';
```